# Can I move my flight schedule after VFS interview?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, vfs-global

I had a Schengen visa appointment for the Netherlands today with VFS. They kept my travel documents and the tickets. I am wondering if I will be to make any changes to the itinerary before the embassy makes any decision on my visa.

If I make any changes, will it affect the decision?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't know if it would affect your decision, but your reservation is very likely on an electronic ticket, which means you should be able to change it by calling the airline and supplying them with your 6-character booking code. (Since I don't know if it would affect your decision, I'm not posting this as an answer yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Making changes to an itinerary that accompanied the visa application, but prior to issuance, has a certain level of risk. Until the visa decision is made, you would not know the validity dates nor would you even be assured of being granted a visa. Making material changes could affect the visa decision, should verification be attempted and arrangements don't coincide with what was submitted or, worse, can't be confirmed.